# Confusing error message from an incorrect use of dict()

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime-error

I have just come across the construct for d3, where the first parameter is a map, and the rest are unpacked key, values.

```py
>>> d1 = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> d2 = dict(d=4, e=5)
>>> d3 = dict(d1, **d2)
>>> d3
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

So I decided to see what would happen if I left out the unpack operator.

```
>>> d_bad = dict(d1, d2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

My first thought was, clearly dict() can take more than one argument, so why this particular error? My second was, that it is actually complaining about more than one argument of the specific type map, hence `TypeError`. But shouldn't it say so? On the face of it, the text of the error message is plain confusing, or even incorrect. Or is there a reason why it can't be clearer?

Comment: `My first thought was, clearly dict() can take more than one argument` what makes you think that?

Comment: IMHO it would be better if it said "dict expected at most 1 positional arguments, got 2".

Answer (score 1):

as described in the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) these are the possible arguments:

> ```
> class dict(**kwarg) 
> class dict(mapping, **kwarg) 
> class dict(iterable,**kwarg)
> ```

your last case does not match any of them.

you can pass named arguments after the first `mapping` oder `iterable`; but not a second mapping or iterable.

if the error message perfectly accounts for those options is debatable...

Comment: I actually tried out the last case, d_bad, just to experiment, before I looked up the doc. From the doc I then deduced that the error message must have been referring to the number of mapping parameters supplied, or indeed the number of positional arguments as @Goyo says.

Comment: I'm actually looking for an explanation of why the error message is so misleading, not just the reason why d_bad fails.